# How to create a pre-choice selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was interested in creating a temporary screen before a page where someone could choose an option that would determine what they're shown.

Example: Contact page where the screen asks "Are you interested in contacting us regarding a purchase or to talk to our customer team". Once they click an option it would display the corresponding contact form (one emails customer team, the other emails the purchase team).

I'm not sure how to code this as I'm new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript but based on what I've learned so far I'm assuming this is more advanced JavaScript.

Comment: Then the question should be closed as "too broad". Please read [ask]

Comment: I'm asking for a hint @PatrickHund How can I post code if I have no idea how to do this? Just topics or ideas that may revolve around this idea so I can read up and follow that.

Comment: Hints? OK: read up on event listeners (click or change events for your radio buttons or drop-down list or however it is you want to display the options), and read up on [hiding/showing elements from JS by manipulating the CSS.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/showhide-element/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you asking, but it sounds like if you changed the elements' `z-index` values on the click of the buttons, it would work.

You can read more about z-index [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Or, you can use `display`.

Here is an example:

```js
function layerPages(page) {
    if (page == "one") {
         document.getElementById("pageOne").style.display = "block"; // shows first page if that is what is called
    } else if (page == "two") {
         document.getElementById("pageTwo").style.display = "block"; // shows second page if that is what is called
    } else {
     window.alert("error, wrong useage");
    }
    document.getElementById("originalPage").style.display = "none"; // hides main page
}

document.getElementById("buttonOne").addEventListener("click", function 
myfunction() {layerPages("one");}); // adds event listener that states that when the first button is clicked, the first page is shown and the original is hidden using the function "layerPages" (declared above)
document.getElementById("buttonTwo").addEventListener("click", function 
myfunction() {layerPages("two");}); // adds event listener that states that when the second button is clicked, the second page is shown and the original is hidden using the function "layerPages" (declared above)
```

```css
#originalPage {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#pageOne, #pageTwo {
  display: none; /*You need to make sure that both #pageOne and #pageTwo start out as display: none;*/
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#pageTwo {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="originalPage">
<button id="buttonOne">Page One</button>
<button id="buttonTwo">Page Two</button>
</div>
<div id="pageOne"></div>
<div id="pageTwo"></div>

<!--The content goes into each div, I'm sure that you can figure that out-->
```

Comment: But then you'd have to worry about positioning, and opacity, etc. Wouldn't it be simpler to just fiddle with the `style.display` property?

Comment: Great thanks, z-index is new to me but I'll read up on it's usage. Thank you for the snippet too.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a simple example to give you some sense about it, but I would suggest you to get more basic front end training first.

```
if (window.confirm('Do you want load form a?')) {
  document.getElementById('a').style.display = 'block';
} else {
  document.getElementById('b').style.display = 'block';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8LmL4vdr/1/

Comment: I agree with your suggestion. Thanks for this! Will be experimenting with this.